# Couchbase Ottoman nodejs Generic Error, Code:10

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-ottoman, ottoman-node

I am trying to connect to `couchbase` using `ottoman-node` with the following code below.

```
ottoman.bucket = (new couchbase.Cluster(config.couchbase.test.server)).openBucket(config.couchbase.test.bucket, function (err) {
    if (err)
        console.log('Connection Error!', err);
        return;

    console.log('Connection Successful!');
});
```

But I get this error `{ CouchbaseError: Generic error message: 'Generic error', code: 10 }`

Wha does this mean?

Comment: cross-posted to Couchbase forums - https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbaseerror-generic-error-message-generic-error-code-10/9165

Comment: @MatthewGroves because the community on couchbase is so small. :(

Comment: Not criticizing, I just want to link up the two worlds :)

Comment: @MatthewGroves Fair point :) But do have any Idea about this? :/

Comment: I'm not much of a node guy, but maybe could you post some of the other code and I could try it myself? (E.g. what the config obj values are, how you created the ottoman obj)